# SQL Table row is not getting deleted

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**I am having 4 tables**

```
  1. **user** 
     primary key:user_id
  2. **task_details**
     primary key:task_id
     foreign key:user_id
  3.**task_folder**
     primary key:task_folder_id
     foreign key:user_id
  4.**task_details_folder_mapping**
     primary key:task_details_folder_mapping_id
     foreign key:task_id,task_folder_id
```

If I delete one folder from my project then that particular task in that folder must be deleted. But folder and tasks is deleting and updated in the front end. But task which is deleted is still shown in the table task_details. But the folder details are deleted from the tables task_folder and task_details_folder_mapping.

Please do help me to rectify the error. I am using codeigniter

Comment: How would you like us to rectify an error if we do not even know what you are doing?

Comment: I told the scenario already that when I will delete the folder the task in it should be deleted. But in the database it not getting updated in task_details table. Still deleted task is displayed there

Answer (score 1):

Set `ON DELETE CASCADE` in your foreign key column `task_Folder_id` of `task_details_folder_mapping` table

`ON DELETE CASCADE` allows you to delete data from child tables automatically when you delete the data from the parent table.

Comment: Thank you... Let me try once

Answer (score -1):

In phpmyadmin..first of all should make data engine innodb..then go to parent table and add a cascade on deleting primary key  ...
I wish this is helpful for you .thanks

Comment: How will you add ON DELETE CASCADE to primary key? Its not possible.

Comment: In phpmyadmin ...convert your database from myisam to innodb

Comment: But you can not add to primary key. ON DELETE CASCADE can work only with foreign key